# Determining pgrouting version

Tags: pgrouting

Is there a way to know what version of pgrouting I have?

My OS is ubuntu 12.04.

I want to know my pgrouting version because the 1.05 version has some issues with shooting start and the directed graphs and the last stable version which has this algorithm is 1.03.

Comment: How did you install pgrouting? From source(*.tar.gz or git clone) or ubuntu package(apt-get install *)?

Comment: From ubuntu package

Comment: Can you give me the command you used to install it?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gaul-devel \
postgresql-9.1-pgrouting \
postgresql-9.1-pgrouting-dd \
postgresql-9.1-pgrouting-tsp \
pgrouting-workshop

Comment: What do you see in aptitude then??
("/" to search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed it through Ubuntu's package manager, then you could try firing up your terminal and typing

```
apt-show-versions postgresql-9.1-pgrouting
```

That should return the version. You might have to install apt-show-versions

```
apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

Answer (score 22):

Another option would be `select * from pgr_version()`

Comment: This is a much better option, as it works on any OS. Worth mentioning that pgr_version is a function with hard-coded values, that also returns git versions.